# Typescript Can't implement generic function interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generic-programming

I'm trying to implement a generic function interface and I cannot make it work.

**IToken.ts**

```js
export interface IToken {
  token: string;
  expires: number;
}
```

**ITokenMapper.ts**

```js
export interface ITokenMapper {
  <T>(apiResult: any): T;
}
```

**tokenMapper.ts**

```js
import {ITokenMapper} from "./interfaces/ITokenMapper";
import {IToken} from "./interfaces/IToken";

export const tokenMapper: ITokenMapper = function <IToken>(apiResult: any): IToken {
  if(apiResult.token && apiResult.expires) {
    return {token: apiResult.token as string, expires: apiResult.expires as number}
  }
  throw new Error('Unable to parse token');
};
```

Here is a screenshot from `tokenMapper.ts` saying IToken import is unused but I should have a use for it:

[image: tokenMapper.ts]

Edit : Using Typescript 3.0.3

Comment: Try to avoid using `any ` at best. I also do not understand why you use type hinting in your tokenMapper. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What type does your `apiResult` have?

Comment: @k0pernikus I'd create a generic micro application where we could parse result from api token request to a personal interface

Comment: @k0pernikus I don't know, that's to goal of my parser, filter informations from a request and keep token string and when it will expire

Comment: Why not create an Interface directly for your `apiResponse`?

Comment: Because I don't know if the informations fetched from the back will always have an identical shape, it could come from a personal DB, AzureAD, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish your typing with a generic interface `ITokenMapper<T>`

```
interface IToken {
    token: string;
    expires: number;
}

interface ITokenMapper<T> {
    (apiResult: T): T;
}

const tokenMapper: ITokenMapper<IToken> = function (apiResult) {
    if(apiResult.token && apiResult.expires) {
      return { token: apiResult.token as string, expires: apiResult.expires as number};
    }

    throw new Error('Unable to parse token');
};
```

From: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types

Comment: @AdMer Please add in the comment or as an answer of your own what you did change so that it now fits your use-case, so that others with a similar problem may benefit from it as well.

Comment: @k0pernikus sure i just did it

Answer (score 2):

So here is what I changed to make it work

**ITokenMapper.ts -> IMapper.ts** renamed and updated

```js
export type IMapper<T> = (apiResult: any) => T;
```

**tokenMapper.ts -> abpTokenMapper.ts** renamed and updated

```js
import { IMapper } from "../../utils/IMapper";
import { IToken } from "../interfaces/IToken";

export const abpTokenMapper: IMapper<IToken> = (apiResult: any) => {
  if (apiResult.accessToken && apiResult.expireInSeconds) {
    return { token: apiResult.accessToken as string, expires: apiResult.expireInSeconds as number }
  }
  throw new Error('Unable to parse token');
};
```